# springsecurity successHandler deafultTargetUrl does not work in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

my successHandler deafultTargetUrl is this

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.deafultTargetUrl = '/home'
```

home set with permitAll

```
 '/home':     ['permitAll']
```

but when i submit form then home page does not open.

i am try also this

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.deafultTargetUrl = '/home'
```

home controller code is

```
class HomeController {

    def index() {
        render(view:'welcome')
    }
}
```

Comment: ```deafultTargetUrl``` should be ```defaultTargetUrl```.

Comment: thnx sir and pardon me ,i can't vote  to you because, i click twice on vote link by mistake .-ken

Comment: Glad it worked. I posted my comment as an answer if you want to accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deafultTargetUrl` should be `defaultTargetUrl`.